# debugging memory leak in android kernel, addr2line cannot find specific address

Tags: android, debugging, kernel, android-source

its my own compiled kernel. problem is its rebooting when trying to start usb tethering. wifi tethering works.

last_kmesg gave this

```
[  264.185455] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000010
[  264.185638] pgd = 80004000
[  264.185699]     [00000010] *pgd=00000000
[  264.185760] Internal error: Oops: 5     [#1] PREEMPT
[  264.185852] last sysfs file: /sys/devices/virtual/android_usb/android0/bDeviceClass
[  264.186004] Modules linked in: wl12xx_sdio wl12xx mac80211 cfg80211 compat_firmware_class(P) compat
[  264.186187] CPU: 0    Tainted: P        W   (2.6.32.39-MESA-JB-v2.3 #4)
[  264.186340] PC is at name_show+0xc/0x44
[  264.186981] LR is at name_show+0xc/0x44
[  264.190795] pc :     [<803ff2d0>]    lr :     [<803ff2d0>]    psr: a00f0013
[  264.190795] sp : cf15dda8  ip : 80323000  fp : c4e109c0
[  264.202239] r10: 00000004  r9 : c4e109c0  r8 : 00000004
[  264.207458] r7 : 00000004  r6 : cf15c000  r5 : c0b64000  r4 : c0b64000
[  264.213958] r3 : 00000001  r2 : c0b64000  r1 : 00000000  r0 : 00000000
[  264.220489] Flags: NzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment kernel
[  264.227752] Control: 10c57c7d  Table: 4ef24059  DAC: 00000017
[  264.233489] 
[  264.233489] PC: 0x803ff250:
[  264.237731] f250  e2851014 ebfb97b7 e59f301c e5941008 e5930000 ebfb9850 e5940004 e3a01000
[  264.245910] f270  e8bd4070 eafba402 80794fc0 8080a124 e92d4070 e1a05002 ebfba3f7 e5903014
[  264.254058] f290  e1a04000 e3530000 0a000003 e1a01005 e12fff33 e3500000 a8bd8070 e1a00005
[  264.262237] f2b0  e59f1008 e594200c e8bd4070 eaf9bafb 806651b2 e92d4070 e1a05002 ebfba3e6
[  264.270385] f2d0  e5903010 e1a04000 e3530000 0a000003 e1a01005 e12fff33 e3500000 a8bd8070
[  264.278533] f2f0  e1a00005 e59f1008 e5942000 e8bd4070 eaf9baea 80675d73 e92d4073 e1a04000
[  264.286712] f310  e59f60c4 e5963000 e3530000 1a000002 ebffffb1 e2505000 ba000029 e59f50ac
[  264.294860] f330  e1952f9f e2822001 e1851f92 e3310000 1afffffa e5940000 e3a01000 e5842008
[  264.303009] 
[  264.303039] LR: 0x803ff250:
[  264.307281] f250  e2851014 ebfb97b7 e59f301c e5941008 e5930000 ebfb9850 e5940004 e3a01000
[  264.315429] f270  e8bd4070 eafba402 80794fc0 8080a124 e92d4070 e1a05002 ebfba3f7 e5903014
[  264.323608] f290  e1a04000 e3530000 0a000003 e1a01005 e12fff33 e3500000 a8bd8070 e1a00005
[  264.331756] f2b0  e59f1008 e594200c e8bd4070 eaf9bafb 806651b2 e92d4070 e1a05002 ebfba3e6
[  264.339904] f2d0  e5903010 e1a04000 e3530000 0a000003 e1a01005 e12fff33 e3500000 a8bd8070
[  264.348083] f2f0  e1a00005 e59f1008 e5942000 e8bd4070 eaf9baea 80675d73 e92d4073 e1a04000
[  264.356231] f310  e59f60c4 e5963000 e3530000 1a000002 ebffffb1 e2505000 ba000029 e59f50ac
[  264.364379] f330  e1952f9f e2822001 e1851f92 e3310000 1afffffa e5940000 e3a01000 e5842008
[  264.372558] 
[  264.372558] SP: 0xcf15dd28:
[  264.376800] dd28  00000000 800ffc28 00000000 00000041 807a27e4 00000000 8fb634a0 00000000
[  264.384979] dd48  ffffffff cf15dd94 cf15c000 00000004 00000004 80033aac 00000000 00000000
[  264.393127] dd68  c0b64000 00000001 c0b64000 c0b64000 cf15c000 00000004 00000004 c4e109c0
[  264.401275] dd88  00000004 c4e109c0 80323000 cf15dda8 803ff2d0 803ff2d0 a00f0013 ffffffff
[  264.409454] dda8  c0b64000 8002ff9c cf15c000 803ff42c 80752b30 80041d0c 80041ce8 00000005
[  264.417602] ddc8  cf15c010 80042594 00000001 80764d18 80764d18 200f0093 cf612580 00000000
[  264.425750] dde8  00000003 807c8d00 cf15de14 800befc4 cf612580 200f0093 807c8d00 00000000
[  264.433929] de08  00000003 cf612580 cf15de2c 800bfd60 cf629fa4 00000001 cf600908 00000000
[  264.442077] 
[  264.442077] IP: 0x80322f80:
[  264.446350] 2f80  e3803b02 e5950004 e6ff3073 eb00021c e1a00004 eb0947a1 e3a00000 e8bd8038
[  264.454498] 2fa0  e92d4010 e1a04000 e3a02000 e5900004 e59410c0 eb000231 e250c000 b8bd8010
[  264.462646] 2fc0  e38ccc12 e30f3bff e5940004 e3a02000 e59410c0 e00c3003 e8bd4010 ea000208
[  264.470825] 2fe0  e92d4070 e1a04000 e59030e0 e3a02004 e59050dc e59410c0 e0055003 e58050e0
[  264.478973] 3000  e5900004 eb00021d e3500000 b8bd8070 e3c03efe e3150001 13833020 e3150002
[  264.487152] 3020  13833040 e3150004 13833080 e3150008 13833c01 e3150a02 13833b01 e3150901
[  264.495300] 3040  13833b02 e1530000 0a000008 e5940004 e3a02004 e59410c0 e6ff3073 eb0001e8
[  264.503448] 3060  e3500000 a3a06001 aa000001 e8bd8070 e3a06000 e59410dc e3110030 01a00006
[  264.511627] 
[  264.511627] FP: 0xc4e10940:
[  264.515869] 0940  c4e1093c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  264.524017] 0960  0000d3da c4e10964 c4e10964 00000003 c4fc1af1 00000000 00000000 ced0a600
[  264.532196] 0980  8fb98e3c 00000001 00000000 00000000 54b10008 54b0f4c4 00001fe5 c4e1099c
[  264.540344] 09a0  c4e1099c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  264.548522] 09c0  cf150000 00000200 00000000 00000004 8036c1a4 cf138c58 00000000 00000000
[  264.556671] 09e0  ffffff94 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 4f350000
[  264.564819] 0a00  4f33d140 ffc73140 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  264.572998] 0a20  00005a1a c4e10a24 c4e10a24 00000003 c7e2cc71 c7ac75d0 00000000 c885dc00
[  264.581146] 
[  264.581146] R2: 0xc0b63f80:
[  264.585388] 3f80  c0012d00 00040312 0000ffff c0012d00 00040206 0000043f c0012d00 00040204
[  264.593566] 3fa0  00000000 c0022d00 00040113 3effff00 3effff00 c0022d00 0004010c 00000000
[  264.601715] 3fc0  00000000 c0012d00 00040104 0000000f c0022d00 0004000e 00000000 00e000a0
[  264.609893] 3fe0  c0012d00 00040080 7f007f60 c0013f00 66a6a000 000006dc c0022d00 0001009c
[  264.618041] 4000  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  264.626190] 4020  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  264.634368] 4040  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  264.642517] 4060  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  264.650665] 
[  264.650695] R4: 0xc0b63f80:
[  264.654937] 3f80  c0012d00 00040312 0000ffff c0012d00 00040206 0000043f c0012d00 00040204
[  264.663085] 3fa0  00000000 c0022d00 00040113 3effff00 3effff00 c0022d00 0004010c 00000000
[  264.671264] 3fc0  00000000 c0012d00 00040104 0000000f c0022d00 0004000e 00000000 00e000a0
[  264.679412] 3fe0  c0012d00 00040080 7f007f60 c0013f00 66a6a000 000006dc c0022d00 0001009c
[  264.687561] 4000  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  264.695739] 4020  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  264.703887] 4040  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  264.712036] 4060  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  264.720214] 
[  264.720214] R5: 0xc0b63f80:
[  264.724456] 3f80  c0012d00 00040312 0000ffff c0012d00 00040206 0000043f c0012d00 00040204
[  264.732635] 3fa0  00000000 c0022d00 00040113 3effff00 3effff00 c0022d00 0004010c 00000000
[  264.740783] 3fc0  00000000 c0012d00 00040104 0000000f c0022d00 0004000e 00000000 00e000a0
[  264.748931] 3fe0  c0012d00 00040080 7f007f60 c0013f00 66a6a000 000006dc c0022d00 0001009c
[  264.757110] 4000  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  264.765258] 4020  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  264.773406] 4040  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  264.781585] 4060  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  264.789733] 
[  264.789733] R6: 0xcf15bf80:
[  264.794006] bf80  cf623ed8 cf142d60 80764d18 80750ff8 cf15bfbc 800d8f64 83b3f5b3 00000000
[  264.802154] bfa0  00000013 cf142e94 83b3f5b3 00000000 00000000 cf623ec8 80371854 cf138c00
[  264.810302] bfc0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 800d8f7c 00000000 00000000
[  264.818481] bfe0  cf15bfe0 cf15bfe0 00000000 00000000 00000000 80035004 55555555 55555555
[  264.826629] c000  00000000 00000002 00000000 cf142d60 80764db0 00000000 00000017 80764d18
[  264.834808] c020  cf142d60 cf15c000 807c8d00 cf0ffde0 c8274cc0 cf612d60 cf15de94 cf15de40
[  264.842956] c040  805741a8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  264.851104] c060  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  264.859283] 
[  264.859283] R9: 0xc4e10940:
[  264.863525] 0940  c4e1093c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  264.871673] 0960  0000d3da c4e10964 c4e10964 00000003 c4fc1af1 00000000 00000000 ced0a600
[  264.879852] 0980  8fb98e3c 00000001 00000000 00000000 54b10008 54b0f4c4 00001fe5 c4e1099c
[  264.888000] 09a0  c4e1099c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  264.896179] 09c0  cf150000 00000200 00000000 00000004 8036c1a4 cf138c58 00000000 00000000
[  264.904327] 09e0  ffffff94 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 4f350000
[  264.912475] 0a00  4f33d140 ffc73140 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  264.920654] 0a20  00005a1a c4e10a24 c4e10a24 00000003 c7e2cc71 c7ac75d0 00000000 c885dc00
[  264.928802] Process file-storage (pid: 67, stack limit = 0xcf15c2f0)
[  264.935150] Stack: (0xcf15dda8 to 0xcf15e000)
[  264.939483] dda0:                   c0b64000 8002ff9c cf15c000 803ff42c 80752b30 80041d0c
[  264.947662] ddc0: 80041ce8 00000005 cf15c010 80042594 00000001 80764d18 80764d18 200f0093
[  264.955810] dde0: cf612580 00000000 00000003 807c8d00 cf15de14 800befc4 cf612580 200f0093
[  264.963958] de00: 807c8d00 00000000 00000003 cf612580 cf15de2c 800bfd60 cf629fa4 00000001
[  264.972137] de20: cf600908 00000000 cf15de34 800bfddc cf15de64 800d92d0 cf600908 800beb58
[  264.980285] de40: 00000000 cf15c000 200f0093 00000000 cf138c80 00000004 00000000 8002ff40
[  264.988464] de60: cf15de7c 800bfc98 00000000 00000010 cf15c000 600f0013 8036c308 800d570c
[  264.996612] de80: cf15c000 cf6008e0 00000000 800d5794 cf15de98 800d57ec 807eac50 cf138c00
[  265.004760] dea0: 00000000 8036cd04 00000001 cf138c00 00000000 cf15c000 00000004 cf138c00
[  265.012939] dec0: 00000000 cf15c000 00000004 8036f8e8 00000017 807c8d00 0000000a 00000000
[  265.021087] dee0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 8074801c cf142d60 800ddf4c 00000000 00000002
[  265.029235] df00: 80748000 80033f64 c4e109c0 80010013 cf01a068 80365234 806bc58e 8036cedc
[  265.037414] df20: 8002ff84 8fd180e0 cf138c3c cf142e90 00007736 00000000 8002ff84 cf15c000
[  265.045562] df40: cf138c00 00000001 cf138c58 00000004 c4e109c0 00000004 c4e109c0 cf138c00
[  265.053741] df60: 00000200 cf15c000 cf138c58 803718e8 cf138c5c 806bc58e cf624000 80033f64
[  265.061889] df80: cf623ed8 cf142d60 80764d18 80750ff8 cf15dfbc 800d8f64 83574b0d 00000000
[  265.070037] dfa0: 00000013 cf142e94 83574b0d 00000000 00000000 cf623ec8 80371854 cf138c00
[  265.078216] dfc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 800d8f7c 00000000 00000000
[  265.086364] dfe0: cf15dfe0 cf15dfe0 00000000 00000000 00000000 80035004 55555555 55555555
[  265.094543]     [<803ff2d0>] (name_show+0xc/0x44) from     [<803ff42c>] (switch_set_state+0x3c/0x130)
[  265.103057]     [<803ff42c>] (switch_set_state+0x3c/0x130) from     [<8036f8e8>] (handle_exception+0x3f8/0x4c4)
[  265.112426]     [<8036f8e8>] (handle_exception+0x3f8/0x4c4) from     [<803718e8>] (fsg_main_thread+0x94/0x2210)
[  265.121795]     [<803718e8>] (fsg_main_thread+0x94/0x2210) from     [<800d8f7c>] (kthread+0x78/0x80)
[  265.130218]     [<800d8f7c>] (kthread+0x78/0x80) from     [<80035004>] (kernel_thread_exit+0x0/0x8)
[  265.138549] Code: 806651b2 e92d4070 e1a05002 ebfba3e6 (e5903010) 
[  265.146209] ---    [ end trace 1b75b31a2719ed1e ]---
[  265.165191] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception
[  265.165344]     [<8003a260>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0x154) from     [<80573ae0>] (panic+0x54/0x120)
[  265.165557]     [<80573ae0>] (panic+0x54/0x120) from     [<80038038>] (die+0x168/0x194)
[  265.169982]     [<80038038>] (die+0x168/0x194) from     [<8003b3f0>] (__do_kernel_fault+0x64/0x74)
[  265.178222]     [<8003b3f0>] (__do_kernel_fault+0x64/0x74) from     [<8003b5c4>] (do_page_fault+0x1c4/0x1d8)
[  265.187347]     [<8003b5c4>] (do_page_fault+0x1c4/0x1d8) from     [<8003325c>] (do_DataAbort+0x30/0x98)
[  265.196014]     [<8003325c>] (do_DataAbort+0x30/0x98) from     [<80033aac>] (__dabt_svc+0x4c/0x60)
[  265.204254] Exception stack(0xcf15dd60 to 0xcf15dda8)
[  265.209289] dd60: 00000000 00000000 c0b64000 00000001 c0b64000 c0b64000 cf15c000 00000004
[  265.217437] dd80: 00000004 c4e109c0 00000004 c4e109c0 80323000 cf15dda8 803ff2d0 803ff2d0
[  265.225585] dda0: a00f0013 ffffffff
[  265.229095]     [<80033aac>] (__dabt_svc+0x4c/0x60) from     [<803ff2d0>] (name_show+0xc/0x44)
[  265.236968]     [<803ff2d0>] (name_show+0xc/0x44) from     [<803ff42c>] (switch_set_state+0x3c/0x130)
[  265.245483]     [<803ff42c>] (switch_set_state+0x3c/0x130) from     [<8036f8e8>] (handle_exception+0x3f8/0x4c4)
[  265.254852]     [<8036f8e8>] (handle_exception+0x3f8/0x4c4) from     [<803718e8>] (fsg_main_thread+0x94/0x2210)
[  265.264251]     [<803718e8>] (fsg_main_thread+0x94/0x2210) from     [<800d8f7c>] (kthread+0x78/0x80)
[  265.272674]     [<800d8f7c>] (kthread+0x78/0x80) from     [<80035004>] (kernel_thread_exit+0x0/0x8)
[  265.280975] &@panic_name@:*file-storage*
[  265.284942] Rebooting in 10 seconds..
```

i assume the address of the leak is 0x803ff250

```
[  264.233489] PC: 0x803ff250:
```

but when i try to find the address via addr2line

```
addr2line -e ~/vmlinux 0x803ff250
```

it just gave this output

```
??:0
```

any help/pointer/guidance?
i'm not really good at debugging things.
thanks beforehand.

Comment: No, the PC is at 0x803ff2d0.  It might be worth trying the addr2line matching the kernel compiler you used, ie arm-whatever-addr2line.  A simpler option could be just to grep the source tree for the "name_show" function mentioned which the PC is given as being shortly after the start of.  Put some printk's in to check anything that looks suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the objdump to find out your crashed PC in  kernel

i am not familar to addr2line, but it should be usually used at user mode va and used to debugging the user mode program. Not sure if this can finding location of kernel .